# Can't change background color of element on condition using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change background color of element if some element has some appropriate text.

**I think I have troubles with including jQuery.Simple alert is not working.**

I included jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

and added id's to appropriate elements:

```
<td id="method">Some method</td>
<td>RAM_UNITS</td>
<td id="bupa-vic">RAM_MBP</td>
<td>RAM_SCHED</td>
<td>RAM_REBATE</td>
<td id="oop">RAM_OOP_NO_GAP</td>
<td>RAM_OOP_GAP</td>
<td id="total">RAM_TOTAL_EXPENCE</td>
```

now I want to make next action: if method = insurance change background-color of buppa into blue.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#method').text() == 'Insurance' ) {
      $(#bupa-vic).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
    }
    if ( $('#method').text() == 'out of pocket' ) {
      $(#bupa-vic).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
      $(#oop).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
    }
    if ( $('#method').text() == 'Total account' ) {
      $(#total).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work. Also no errors related to jQuery in Google console.

Can someone suggest where is problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `'` in `$(#bupa-vic) => $('#bupa-vic')` http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8ZT/3/

Answer (score 4):

You're are missing a bunch of quotes...notice the incorrect syntax highlighting in your code?

```
$('#bupa-vic').css({'background-color': 'blue'});
--^---------^--
```

Same with all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `console.log( $('#method').text() )` and view a result what you get with this, also dont forget to add `$(#method)` - `$('#method')` commas.

Comment: Thanks. Log says that it contains `Insurance `, but background color isn't changing.

Comment: I think is something wrong with your other code or structure, here the examle whitch works for me, checkerout:
http://jsfiddle.net/GomatoX/EzXVu/

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use the `.contains()` method with jQuery, it's much simpler and you can make any anount to account for the different words:

```
$("td#method:contains('Insurance')");
$('td#bupa-vic').css("background-color", "blue");
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Hpj59/1/

Comment: Thanks, I think I have problem with including file.